# Minor Manipulations to show the connection between Conditional Expectation and Covariance - Can someone help?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables; I want to show now two things that should actually be not too hard to prove:

1. If $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)=\mathbb{E}(X)$, then Cov$(X,Y)=0$
2. If $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)=a+bY$, then b=Cov$(X,Y)/\sigma_X^2$, where $\sigma_X^2$ is the variance of $X$ and we assume that it exists and is non-zero.

Now for both things I should use the law of iterated expectations:

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(A\mid B))=\mathbb E (A)$$However I don't really see how to do it - can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

For each question, use the fact that:

$\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)~{=\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y)\\=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)Y)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y)}$

For (b) also use that: $\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))$ and $\sigma_X^2= \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y))-\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))^2$

Comment: I am a litte confused I know by the law of iterated expectations that: $\mathbb E(\mathbb E(X\mid Y))=\mathbb E (X)$ but why can I also assume that: $\mathbb E(\mathbb E(X\mid Y)Y)=\mathbb E (XY)$

Comment: Because $\mathsf E(XY\mid Y)=\mathsf E(X\mid Y)\;Y$ since $Y$ is relatively constant to $Y$. For any particular value in the support:  $$\mathsf E(XY\mid Y{=}y) ~{= \mathsf E(yX\mid Y{=}y) \\= y\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y{=}y)}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp You should have $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X^2\mid Y]]$ in the expression for the variance of $X$.